# how to make the radio buttons work in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, function, dom

I am learning the basics of JavaScript and still get some of the basics wrong and I tried to make it work, but failed. I am trying to make the message change font weight when one of the radio button is checked. JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Eg87P/

**HTML/JavaScript Code:**

```
<div id="prob2">
    <h1>Radio Buttons</h1>
    <p id="msg">Message</p>
    <input type="radio" value="bold" name="rdFontStyle" id="bold"/>Bold<br/>
    <input type="radio" value="italic" name="rdFontStyle" id="italic"/>Italic<br/>
    <input type="radio" value="underline" name="rdFontStyle" id="underline"/>Underline<br/>
    <input type="radio" value="regular" name="rdFontStyle" id="regular"/>Regular<br/>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function msg1
    {
        var msg = document.getElementById("msg");

        if(document.getElementById("bold").checked)
        {       
            if(msg.hasAttribute("style"))
            {
                msg.removeAttribute("style");
            }
            msg.style.fontWeight = "bold";
        }
        else if(document.getElementById("italic").checked)
        {   
            if(msg.hasAttribute("style"))
            {
                msg.removeAttribute("style");
            }
            msg.style.fontWeight = "italic";
        }
        else if(document.getElementById("underline").checked)
        {
            if(msg.hasAttribute("style"))
            {
                msg.removeAttribute("style");
            }
            msg.style.fontWeight = "underline";
        }
        else if(document.getElementById("regular").checked)
        {
            if(msg.hasAttribute("style"))
            {
                msg.removeAttribute("style");
            }
            msg.style.fontWeight = "normal";
        }
    }
    msg1();
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: You must bind a change event to the radiobuttons, in this change event you can call the msg1() method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open your JavaScript console and read the error message:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

`function msg1` should be `function msg1()`

---

> when one of the radio button is checked

If you want to react to a radio button being checked then you need to [listen](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) for an event before running your function. At the moment you are running it immediately.

```
document.getElementById('prob2').addEventListener('change', msg1);
```

---

```
msg.style.fontWeight = "italic";
```

Italic isn't a font-weight. It is a font-style.

```
msg.style.fontStyle = "italic";
```

---

```
msg.style.fontWeight = "underline";
```

Underline isn't a font-weight. It is a type of text-decoration.

```
msg.style.textDecoration = "underline";
```

---

```
msg.style.fontWeight = "normal";
```

Normal is a font-weight, but it makes little sense to set it explicitly here since it is the default and you've just removed the other styles.

Comment: thanks, but the problem with yours is that it does not change to italic or underline, only bold and regular. I debugged and it went through the statements but did nothing to change the style.

Comment: No, that's *another* problem with yours. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Never mind, I got it. italic is `fontStyle` and underline `textDecoration`.

Answer (score 1):

You're not running the msg1() function when the user clicks on the radio button, only once at script loading.
Add a onClick on each radio button which calls msg1();
And your function definition as previously commented.

Answer (score 1):

```
var msg = document.getElementById("msg");

document.getElementById("bold").addEventListener("change", function() {
       if (msg.hasAttribute("style")) {
           msg.removeAttribute("style");
       }

       msg.style.fontWeight = "bold";
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You never call the javascript function on the change of the radio buttons. I suggest adding the following:

```
<input type="radio" value="bold" name="rdFontStyle" id="bold" onchange="msg1()"/>Bold<br/>
<input type="radio" value="italic" name="rdFontStyle" id="italic" onchange="msg1()"/>Italic<br/>
<input type="radio" value="underline" name="rdFontStyle" id="underline" onchange="msg1()"/>Underline<br/>
<input type="radio" value="regular" name="rdFontStyle" id="regular" onchange="msg1()"/>Regular<br/>
```

Give that a try and see what happens =)

EDIT: You also need to add `()` after your declaration of the function:

```
function msg1()
{
...
}
```

Furthermore, you should use the correct style properties. The following works:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function msg1()
{
    var msg = document.getElementById("msg");

    if(document.getElementById("bold").checked)
    {       
        if(msg.hasAttribute("style"))
        {
            msg.removeAttribute("style");
        }
        msg.style.fontWeight = "bold";
    }
    else if(document.getElementById("italic").checked)
    {   
        if(msg.hasAttribute("style"))
        {
            msg.removeAttribute("style");
        }
        msg.style.fontStyle = "italic";
    }
    else if(document.getElementById("underline").checked)
    {
        if(msg.hasAttribute("style"))
        {
            msg.removeAttribute("style");
        }
        msg.style.textDecoration = "underline";
    }
    else if(document.getElementById("regular").checked)
    {
        if(msg.hasAttribute("style"))
        {
            msg.removeAttribute("style");
        }
        msg.style.fontStyle = "normal";
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: I type too slow, others beat me to it =P